Issue with GitLab Plugin in Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline - URL Encoding Problem
We are setting up a CI/CD Pipeline process for our SFDX project.
We've used GitLab as our source code repository.
And Jenkins - Multibranch pipeline project for deployment.
I'm encountering an issue with the GitLab Plugin in my Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline setup. When attempting to clone my GitLab project using SSH key authentication, I'm facing an error in the pipeline script at the 'checkout scm' command. The error log indicates a problem with the Git URL being encoded incorrectly. Here's the error log for reference:
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential id_ed25519
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --resolve-git-dir D:\Jenkins\workspace\LI-DevOps_main@2\.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url %255bgit@gitlab.com:22222]:akashkhichi/salesforceproject.git # timeout=10
Fetching without tags
Fetching upstream changes from %255bgit@gitlab.com:22222]:akashkhichi/salesforceproject.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.22.0.windows.1'
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- %255bgit@gitlab.com:22222]:akashkhichi/salesforceproject.git +refs/heads/main:refs/remotes/origin/main # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from %255bgit@gitlab.com:22222]:akashkhichi/salesforceproject.git

It seems the SSH URL i.e. [git@gitlab.com:22222]:akashkhichi/salesforceproject.git is getting encoded to %255bgit@gitlab.com:22222]:akashkhichi/salesforceproject.git.
We've verified the configurations for the GitLab URL. And the SSH key is also working fine.
In attempting to resolve the issue, I verified the configuration settings for the GitLab URL and ensured that the SSH key was correctly configured and functioning. I also reviewed the Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline configuration to ensure that all settings related to GitLab integration were correctly set up.
We've tried the Git plugin for the same process and it worked fine but we have to use the GitLab plugin to utilize it's features.

Why do you have square brackets in your url? You said you "verified the configurations for the GitLab URL". Can I see the clone command and the output?

Yes , I've checked the GitLab sever URL in the Jenkins system configuration i.e. https://gitlab.com.
Also, I've verified that the command - git clone [git@gitlab.com:22222]:akashkhichi/salesforceproject.git is working fine.
It seems that checkout scm command (which we have used for Jenkins multibranch pipeline script ) is somehow encoding the URL double times for the starting character i.e '[' to retrieve the hostname, port number etc.

The scp-like syntax for repo urls with the square brackets is less popular and its usage leads to issues like you are describing. I suggest switching to a more common ssh:// style:
ssh://git@gitlab.com:22222/akashkhichi/salesforceproject.git


Hi, Yes keeping the SSH URL like: ssh://git@gitlab.com:22222/akashkhichi/salesforceproject.git should resolve the issue.
But How to we use this URL format in checkout SCM for multibranch pipeline.
We tried updating the URL with credentials, it resolves the error but affects the multibranch pipeline functionalty.
checkout scm: ([
$class: 'GitSCM',
userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '******',url: ${project_url}]],
branches: [[name: 'refs/tags/${project_tag}']]
])
As, we cant change the SSH URL from the GitLab.

How does it affect the functionality?

For freestyle project we can get the source-target branches that we can specify as well and it works fine.
Yes, we can do the same in multipipeline project to paramterize the checkout scm call but it doesn't fetch the merge request changes properly.

So it does fetch the merge request changes in the multibranch project, but not properly? What does that mean?
